# unable to install modules using pip

Tags: python, module

I newly installed python 2.7.10 which came with pre installed pip python installer.

I'm unable to install any python modules using pip in python
I tries installing through CMD in widows

For example if i'm trying to install twilio using CMD prompt

**C:python27>pip install twilio**

Cmd Prompt is not giving any errors and it's not proceeding after i used pip install !I tried uninstalling python and installed again but again it's same

[Error while installing from python terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jisC.png)

[Commond prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drZMq.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `pip` in a terminal, but not in the Python shell.  It is a bash command, not Python syntax.  In other words, use `pip` *before* you type "python".

Comment: I tried but still it's same, Could you please explain me in detail

Comment: In [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jisC.png) picture, you type `python` into the terminal to start the python shell.  You then use `pip` within the python shell.  I am saying type `pip...` *before* you type `python` so that you are using it outside of the python shell.  I tried it, however, and it looks like that package does not exist.

Comment: I found the problem: you need to use `twilio`, not `twillio`.

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the module name (use "twi**l**io", instead of "twi**ll**io"). And off course you should do it in the command prompt and **not** in python shell...

;)

Try this:

```
c:\>
pip install twilio
```

Comment: they problem is not only with twilio but with every other module

Comment: what does it say when you execute the command: pip install twilio

Comment: I have to type code in command prompt or in python terminal ?

Comment: If i tried the code c:\>pip install twilio and after pressing enter it's not showing any error currsor moves to next line and remain there ! and not proceeding further

Comment: execute just the following: pip install twilio

Comment: i've added "c:\>" in order to show, that this must be executed in the command shell and NOT in Python shell

Comment: Please find the image 2 command prompt error ! in my question

Comment: I spell checked it as Twilio still it's same

Comment: I downloaded Twilio package is there any way to install it manually ?

Comment: you can install "wheel" packages by executing: pip install package_name.whl, but for that you would need a wheel package file

Comment: alternatively you can try: python setup.py install, you must be in the directory with downloaded Twilio source files

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem

Add the following to the environment path in windows:
"C:>python27\scripts;" (Please paste without the quotes)
This helped me in solving my problem !